# get data date using <= codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I have data looking like this

[image]

I want show all before `01-08-2018` record (included 01-08-2018)
but currently need to fill in 02-08-2018, then able to found 01-08-2018 record

ive tried get data like this  this is my where clause:

```
$this->db->where("a.created_date <=",date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end_date)));
```

but its only show data before 01-08-2018 record not included 01-08-2018

i really bad in english. please help

Comment: try with this : `$this->db->where("date(a.created_date) <= ", date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end_date)));`

Comment: @pradeep its work thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Add `date` function before `a.created_date` like this :

```
$this->db->where("date(a.created_date) <= ", date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end_date)));
```

For more : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: pleasure is mine, happy coding, sir pls do upvote my answer also